# simplifying the trigonometric expression $\frac{\cot\theta - \tan\theta}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta} + \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm stuck on this expression for which I don't have any answer.
$$\frac{\cot\theta - \tan\theta}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$
Need some help on the simplifying steps.
[image]

Here is what I get from a calculator

Comment: To better assist you please indicate what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck. This allows people to better tailor their answer to your skill level. Additional then people won't complete and say that this isn't a homework site.

Comment: @IanMiller I need to simplify it

Comment: You do realize none of this will prepare you for your upcoming test?

Comment: Find a common denominator, and go from there. It's as simple as it seems https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rx2gj-vDms

Answer (score 4):

If you let $\cos\theta$ be $c$ and $\sin\theta$ be $s$ then you have:
$$ \frac{\frac{c}{s}-\frac{s}{c}}{s+c}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{\frac{c^2}{s}-s+s+c}{(s+c)c}=\frac{\frac{cs+c^2}{s}}{sc+c^2} =\frac{cs+c^2}{s(cs+c^2)}=\frac{1}{s}$$
or it can be simplifed to:
$$\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

cancell s+c in num and den

$$\frac{c/s- s/c}{s+c}+\frac{1}{c}= ( c-s)/s c + ... $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed answer:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{\cot\theta-\tan\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}&=\frac{\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}-\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta}\tag{1}\label{ko-eq1}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos \theta}}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta}\tag{2}\label{ko-eq2}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos \theta}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta}\tag{3}\label{ko-eq3}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta}\tag{4}\label{ko-eq4}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta+\sin\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}{\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}\tag{5}\label{ko-eq5}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{2}\theta\cancel{-\sin^{2}\theta}\cancel{+\sin^{2}\theta}+\sin\theta\cos \theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}\tag{6}\label{ko-eq6}\\
&=\frac{\cos^{2}\theta+\sin\theta\cos \theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}\tag{7}\label{ko-eq7}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{\cos\theta}\bcancel{\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}}{\sin\theta\cancel{\cos\theta}\bcancel{\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}}\tag{8}\label{ko-eq8}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\\
&=\csc\theta
\end{align}\\
$$
\eqref{ko-eq1}: Expand $\cot\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ as $\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ and $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, respectively.
\eqref{ko-eq2}: Find common denominator of $\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}-\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$.
\eqref{ko-eq3}: Rewrite $\frac{\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos \theta}}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}$ as $\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos \theta}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}$ and multiply.
\eqref{ko-eq4}: Multiplication resut.
\eqref{ko-eq5}: Find common denominator of $\frac{\cos^{2}\theta-\sin^{2}\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta\left(\sin \theta+\cos \theta\right)}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$ and continue.
\eqref{ko-eq6}: Cancel the terms.
\eqref{ko-eq7}: After cancellation. 
\eqref{ko-eq8}: Final cancellation and finish.
**I hope this helps.**